# How can I apply a table style to an individual column with Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a single table where I want certain columns banded in a particular color. I tried conditional formatting, but it has an issue where I have to scroll the screen up and down for it to "catch up" and refresh so to speak.

if that is not possible, can I split into several tables with their own style and have them "linked" somehow (so that I can filter on a column and have it align the other tables accordingly)?

Edit: Ok not sure how that isn't clear. but here's an example

```
ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1:D6"), , xlYes).Name = "MyTable"
ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).TableStyle = "MyStyle"  'this isn't valid, but that idea
```

Edit2: I figured out how to get my alternative conditional formatting to work. Before, I was having to scroll down and then back up for it to refresh. Turning off banded rows(via table design menu or code) fixes that problem. Code used to turn off:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MyTable").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = False
```

Comment: You can apply either conditional formatting (if necessary), or just a simple (non-conditional) formatting to any cell or group of cells (that could be Range, Row, Column etc). You need to add some clarity to your question and include your sample VBA code as it's tagged Excel-VBA (please notice, that SO is mostly about practical coding issues/resolution, it's not intended to be a tutorial website on general computer literacy). Regards,

Comment: You color columns based on what? Column name? Column number?

Comment: I have a table style that is set up as banded columns("MyStyle" in the example above). I want to apply that table style to a particular column(i.e., ListColumns(1) or ListColumns("myColumn")) and not to the entire table. Apparently something like that is not possible.